# NSLocalizedDescription=Object StringOfNumbers/post1/StringOfNumbers.StringOfNumbers.jpg does not exist

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

When I press a button which takes me to another view controller which is supposed to download a url of an image in firebase so that it can be displayed in a imageView. I receive the following message in the console:

> Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13010 "Object 8MFEIQKyGuTnMI89kMG2E8D9IZ2/post1/153511633.59902.jpg does not exist." UserInfo={object=8MFEIQKyGuTnMI89kGF2E8D9IZ2/post1/1535511633.59902.jpg, ResponseBody=`NoSuchKey`The specified key does not exist.No such object: prjpracticearraybasicimg.appspot.com/8MFEIQKyGuTnMI89kMGF2E8D9IZ2/post1/1535511633.59902.jpg, bucket=yubipracticearraybasicimg1.appspot.com, data=<3c3f786d 6c207665 7273696f 6e3d2731 2e302720 656e636f 64696e67 3d275554 462d3827 3f3e3c45 72726f72 3e3c436f 64653e4e 6f537563 684b6579 3c2f436f 64653e3c 4d657373 6167653e 5466520 73706563 69666965 6420665 7920646f 6573206e 6f742065 78697374 2e3c2f4d 65737361 67653ec 44657461 696c733e 4e6f2073 75636820 6f626a65 63743a20 7975269 70726163 74696365 61727261 79626173 6963696d 67312e61 70707370 6f742e63 6f6d2f38 4d464549 514b7947 75546e4d 4938396b 4d474632 45384439 495a322f 706f7374 312f3135 33353531 31363333 2e353939 30322e6a 70673c2f 44657461 696c733e 3c2f4572 726f723e>, data_content_type=application/xml; charset=UTF-8, NSLocalizedDescription=Object 8MFEIQKyGuTnMI89kMGF28D9IZ2/post1/155511633.59902.jpg does not exist., ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus, ResponseErrorCode=404}

The following is my code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

class PhaseOneViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var p1ImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func loadImages(_ sender: Any) {
        self.downloadImages(folderPath: "\(Storage.storage().reference().child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("post\(takePicViewController().finalPost + PhotoArray.sharedInstance.numberPost)").child(ImageUploadManager().imageName))", success: { (img) in
            self.p1ImageView.image = img
            print(img)
        }) { (error) in
            print("here is errorrrrrrrrrrr",  error)
        }
    }

    func downloadImages(folderPath:String,success:@escaping (_ image:UIImage)->(),failure:@escaping (_ error:Error)->()){
//        for i in 0 ..< 194 {
            // Create a reference with an initial file path and name
            let reference = Storage.storage().reference().child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("post\(takePicViewController().finalPost + PhotoArray.sharedInstance.numberPost)").child(ImageUploadManager().imageName)
            reference.getData(maxSize: (3 * 1024 * 1024)) { (data, error) in
                if let _error = error {
                    print(_error)
                    failure(_error)
                } else {
                    if let _data  = data {
                        let myImage:UIImage! = UIImage(data: _data)
                        success(myImage)
                        self.p1ImageView.image = myImage
                    }
                }
            }
        //}
    }
}
```

The Database tree structure is as follows

> Posts/UID/post#/ImageURLs-URL1, URL2...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Pls, show your google.console database tree

Comment: Updated teh question with it